# Userform Drop down list VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

All,

I have created a Userform (Userform 3) which I wish to have a basic drop down list of 4 Items - Apples / Oranges / Pears / bananas. (Hard coded in the background VBA) and if none of the selections are selected by the users to exit sub.

Please can someone advise how I would do this?

Inserted picture for reference?

[image]

Comment: Do what exactly? Exit if nothing is selected? `If cmb.listindex=-1 then exit sub`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To populate the `Fruits_CB` combo-box on `UserForm_Initialize` event use the code below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

' populate "Fruits_CB" Combo-Box with fruits
With Me.Fruits_CB
    .Clear ' clear previous items (not to have "doubles")
    .AddItem "Apples"
    .AddItem "Oranges"
    .AddItem "Pears"
    .AddItem "Bananas"
End With

End Sub
```

If the user is not selecting any item from the list, and then clicks the button, use the `Sub` below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Me.Fruits_CB.ListIndex = -1 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    ' Do something    
End If  

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the above - My Userform is called UserForm3 which causes an error on the lines "Fruits_CB" can you advise how I fix this?

Comment: Fruits_CB is the name of the combobox, the userform is referenced by the "Me" keyword. You need to change Fruits_CB to whatever your combobox is called. @SeanBailey

Comment: @SeanBailey did you understand what eirikdaude wrote to you in the comment above ?

Comment: No real need to clear the combobox in the `Initialize` event. I'd also recommend using `List` with an array rather than `AddItem`. FWIW.