# Is there a way to choose the location in Outlook for appointments and meetings from a user-created drop down list?

Tags: vba, outlook

My employer requires some pretty specific information in the "location" field of my Outlook calendar appointments and meetings.  It's time consuming to open each meeting invite, etc. to add the specific information.  I have a list of possible locations, and I'm looking for a way to select from that list easily...I have found some VBA that will allow for a drop down on a template to select the subject, but not the location.  And, I'm not sure that will work for meeting invites that I don't create.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I found related to the drop down for the subject.

```
'** The following code goes in a userform **

' Adapted for a single choice

Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim msg As String
Dim Check As String

Dim currItem As MailItem

'Generate a list of the selected items
With ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            msg = .List(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

If msg = vbNullString Then
    'If nothing was selected, tell user and let them try again
    MsgBox "Nothing was selected!  Please make a selection!"
    Exit Sub

Else

    Set currItem = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
    currItem.Subject = msg
    Unload Me

End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me.ListBox1
     'Clear the rowsource in case it has been set
    .RowSource = ""
     'Add the items
    .AddItem ("Cat")
    .AddItem ("Dog")
    .AddItem ("Gerbil")
    .AddItem ("Lizard")
    .AddItem ("Rat")
    .AddItem ("Snake")
    .AddItem ("Turtle")
End With

End Sub


 '** The following code goes in a standard module **

Sub Launch()
'This code will launch the userform
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

I also found this code, but I would need to change this to allow for choosing different locations.

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertConfCallInfo()
Dim myItem As AppointmentItem
    On Error GoTo lbl_Exit
    Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    myItem.Location = "CALL: (866) 555-1212 / CODE: 9854101812"
    'myItem.Display 'Not required as the item is already displayed.
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't tried any code yet.  I'll add the code I found above.

Comment: I actually could make the second set of code work, but I'd like to be able to apply the code by clicking on a button in the ribbon while the appointment is selected rather than having to open the appointment.

Comment: `Set myItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro with a user form from where you could choose the [Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.location) for appointment items. The [Userform Drop down list VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448025/userform-drop-down-list-vba) page explains how to populate the drop down control at startup.

Also you may consider create a COM add-in where you could create a form region with a drop down control. It is up to you which way is to choose.

Answer (score 0):

Once you verify `currItem` is an `AppointmentItem` you can update `.Location`.

```vb
'** The following code goes in a userform **

Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim msg As String
Dim currItem As Object

Set currItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

If TypeOf currItem Is AppointmentItem Then

    'Generate a list of the selected items
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                msg = .List(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
        
    If msg = vbNullString Then
        'If nothing was selected, tell user and let them try again
        MsgBox "Nothing was selected!  Please make a selection!"
    Else
        currItem.Location = msg
        Unload Me
    End If
    
End If

End Sub


Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me.ListBox1
    'Clear the rowsource in case it has been set
    .RowSource = ""
    'Add the items
    .AddItem ("CALL: (866) 555-1212 / CODE: 9854101812")
    .AddItem ("Dog")
    .AddItem ("Gerbil")
    .AddItem ("Lizard")
    .AddItem ("Rat")
    .AddItem ("Snake")
    .AddItem ("Turtle")
End With

End Sub
```

```vb
'** The following code goes in a standard module **

Sub Launch()
'This code will launch the userform
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  When I run the code, I get the message "Method or Data member not found".  It shows the error at the "With Me. LIstBox1" line.

Comment: Possibly the name of the listbox is not ListBox1.